# how to pass type thought method and return diffrent list types

Tags: c#

Ok, so this kinda goes over my head a little. also, I don't even know if it is possible to do so

I really don't even know the terms for a lot of this

First off this is for space engineers a game I play that has open c# script to interact with the game and I have found it very fun and a great way to learn some basics of code

Now what I'm trying to do is make a method, I think that is what it is called its this "internal List<> GetBlocksWithName", and what this method would do is search all blocks on a ship and then convert it to the right type then return a list of that type

but my issue is that I want to pass the 'type' I want to convert to at the end. not only if I try to call the method does it tell me that it's not valid. when I try to use the type that is passed through in the method as a type it says it's not a type

also, I'm not sure how to send the list back if its a different type each time

here is the code I'm using

```
    internal void BlockScan()
    {
        GetBlocksWithName(IMyMotorAdvancedStator, "SolarHing"); // <- compile error IMyMotorAdvancedStator ('IMyMotorAdvancedStator' is a type, witch is not vaild in the give context)
        return;
    }
    internal List<> GetBlocksWithName(Type blockType,string nameOfBlocks) // <- compile error List<>(Unexpected use of an unbound generic name) its because of an unfinshed return not sure how to specife the type if it will be different every time
    {
        List<IMyTerminalBlock> temp = new List<IMyTerminalBlock>();
        GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName(nameOfBlocks, temp);
        return temp.ConvertAll(x => (blockType)x); // <- compile error blockType ('blockType' is a varible but is used like a type)
    }
```

I know that there is a lot of stuff in there that is very specific to space engineers script but if someone could help me out would be of great help thanks in advance

Comment: If the developer knows the identifier of the `blockType`, you can declare a generic type for the `GetBlcoksWithName()` instead of `blockType` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
internal void BlockScan()
{
    GetBlocksWithName<IMyMotorAdvancedStator>("SolarHing"); 
    return;
}

internal List<T> GetBlocksWithName<T>(string nameOfBlocks) 
{
    List<IMyTerminalBlock> temp = new List<IMyTerminalBlock>();
    GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName(nameOfBlocks, temp);
    return temp.ConvertAll(x => (T)x); 
}
```

You pass in the Type = T as a generic, and use the Generic T to convert your variable `x` to the correct type.

Have a look at [Generic programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) in the documentation. To get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much as soon as you told me about the generic type everything kinda just clicked cause when looking at the documentation of the API they use T a lot and now I know why. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I would recommend using a different name then `T`, something that makes sense in your use case. Like `T...` since you can have more then 1 generic type parameter, and T, T1, T2, isn't providing a lot of information.